# find several texts in sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a column that contains html details in it and within each column, the html contains different http links. I need to find out all the http links in each column.

e.g.: column 1 Row 1

```
html 
... 
a href = http://www.column1.com....... 
img src=http://www.pic1.com/images/im.jpg...
...
/html
```

column 1 Row 2

```
html 
...
a href = http://www.column2.com.......  
img src="http://www.pic2.com/images/im.jpg".... 
/html
```

in the result I need to get the following list :

- link1 in first column1 in href
  domain in the first column img link
- link2 in second column2 in href
  domain in the second column img2 link

Could anyone help me to find this as i don't have a clue at all what to do and I'm not good using sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can use `charindex` to try and find index of `http://` and then you need to find end of URL (it depends on you data, space or ").

you can also write CLR scalar function, implementing regular expression find

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class CLR
{
    [SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "FillRow")]
    public static IEnumerable RegexMatch(string pattern, string text)
    {
        var r = new Regex(pattern);
        return r.Matches(text);
    }

    public static void FillRow(Object obj, out SqlInt32 index, out SqlString match)
    {
        var m = (Match)obj;
        index = new SqlInt32(m.Groups[0].Index + 1);
        match = new SqlString(m.Groups[0].Value);
    }
}
```

Then you need to create assembly on your SQL Server from this class library

```
create assembly CLR from 'C:\CLR.dll' with permission_set = safe
```

Then you can create function

```
create function RegexMatch(@pattern nvarchar(4000), @text nvarchar(4000))
returns table ([index] int, match nvarchar(4000))
as external name CLR.CLR.RegexMatch
```

Comment: Thanks Romanhow can i write CLR scalar function? any examples that might help me?

Comment: :) If you hover your mouse near left upper corner of an answer, you'll see up and down arrows, they allow you to upvote and downvote questions and answers. I've never actually accepted an answer (I still didn't post a qustion), but I suppose that you can accept an answer by pressing check sign near arrows.